# No se visualiza el mapa de mi app que subi a la play store

Tags: android, android-studio

Subí una app a la play store donde tiene un apartado de visualización de un mapa, pero cuando lo descargo de la play store no me funciona el mapa
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando emulo mi app en android studio o en mi telefono si se visualiza
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Conecta el dispositivo por USB a tu PC, inicia Android Studio e intenta **usar la App descargada desde Play Store**. Revisa el Logcat de Android Studio, allí debería decirte qué está fallando.

Comment: Me pasó una vez a mí también. Lo que hice fue correr la aplicación en `release` mode en Android Studio. Si el mapa on carga es porque debes añadir tu API key en el folder correcto en `release`.